# Why does [ -t /tmp -o -f /tmp ] throw "too many arguments"

Tags: bash

In a bash session, I can execute the following command successfully:

```
[ -e /tmp -o -f /tmp ]
```

However, the following command fails with the error message *[: too many arguments*:

```
[ -t /tmp -o -f /tmp ]
```

I cannot explain why the second command fails since both, `-e` and the replacement `-t` are unary operators and I didn't change the syntax of the entire expression.

Comment: Have you read the `test` [manual page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/test.1.en), the `-t` option accepts a file descriptor (integer), not a path (string).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I have undeleted the question as it seems interesting to you. I originally deleted it because I didn't read the manual page and after reading it, it clearly states that `-t` requires an integer (and I thought it requires a path to `/dev/fd/n`).

Answer (score 4):

While the `-t` operator is a unary operator that expects a number in bash (not an arithmetic expression like in ksh or zsh), that doesn't explain the error you're getting.

It doesn't explain either why `[ -t /tmp ]` or `[ X -a -t -a Y ]` return false without an error.

If you look at the code for that `test`/`[` builtin, you'll see that there are [remnants there](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/test.c?h=bash-5.2#n489) from the time when `[ -t ]` was short for `[ -t 1 ]` and that haven't been removed after that was discontinued and the code was updated to follow the POSIX algorithm.

See [this bug report](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2023-07/msg00046.html) for details.

Also note that the binary `-a`/`-o` operators should **not** be used. They've been deprecated by POSIX for decades, and make for unreliable test expressions.

Use:

```
[ -d /tmp ] || [ -f /tmp ]
```

Instead.

Note that `-f` implies `-e`, so `[ -e /tmp -o -f /tmp ]` or `[ -e /tmp ] || [ -f /tmp ]` don't make much sense and can be written `[ -e /tmp ]` which is a test of whether `/tmp` exists (after symlink resolution) whether it is a *regular* file (`-f`) or not.

In `zsh`:

```
$ zsh -c '[ -t /tmp ]'
zsh:1: bad math expression: operand expected at `/tmp'
```

`/tmp` is indeed a *bad math expression*, the *operand expected* refers to the `/` division math operator, not the `-t` `[` operator.

```
$ zsh -c '[ -t foo/tmp ]'
zsh:1: division by zero
```

This time a valid math expression (`foo` variable devided by `tmp` variable), but leads to a division by 0 as `$tmp` is not set and is therefore considered as 0.

```
$ zsh -o nounset -c '[ -t foo/tmp ]'
zsh:1: tmp: parameter not set
```

The `nounset` option is useful to detect variables used uninitialised.

```
$ foo=4 tmp=2 zsh -o nounset -c '[ -t foo/tmp ] &&
   printf "fd %d is open on a tty device\n" foo/tmp'
fd 2 is open on a tty device
```

Comment: also somehow Bash manages to accept `[ -t -a -t 1 ]` and return falsy, even when all fds are connected to a terminals.